# Locating offset of cursor in a div contentEditable (something similar to mentions on G+)

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I am trying to create something to similar to Google+ mentions, where you would include a user in your post with the + character. The minute you type +, you are given a list of users to choose from. I've seen a few examples, mainly plugins that are massive and do much more than what I am looking for.

So this is the functionality I am hoping to achieve:

> 1. User types in contentEditable div
> 2. User enters @ char
> 3. **Script detects @ char and finds offset relative to container (in pixels)**
> 4. Server side query is done and passes JSON data back to client
> 5. List appears just under the @ char where it was typed **using offset of the @ char**

I've searched and searched and the only results I end up with are not what I am looking for. I usually end up with cursor/caret position relative to the text.

I am not opposed to using a plugin (hopefully minimalistic). I am using jQuery 1.7.

Thank you,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

jquery.mentionsInput is very minimal.

http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/

Comment: Awesome. This is what I was looking for. Going to give it a shot and see how it works out. I'll report back.

Comment: After trying this out, it looks that there are too many dependencies with this plugin. I do like the concept and it is much easier approach opposed to what I was trying. It looks like what I will end up doing is creating a depedentless jQuery plugin that will achieve the same and I will post it back here.

Comment: It looks like it only requires jQuery and Underscore.js. jQuery is pretty standard, and if you haven't used Underscore before you'll love it! very useful for a number of things and a relatively small size.
But please share if you make your own plugin!